# Does my iOS 7 app need an iCloud On/Off Switch?

Tags: ios, core-data, ios7, icloud

Are there any scenarios in which it makes sense to include an on/off switch for iCloud in an app? I know that users can disable iCloud for my app in **Settings**, and they can delete all iCloud data for my app under **Manage Storage** in Settings.

I can't think of any reason to have one, but I'm relatively new to iCloud/Core Data and don't want to mess anything up.

Thanks!

Comment: It is your app.  You make the call according to functionality of your app.  You should define what is good user experience is.

Comment: If you have two different places (one OS provided and one in your app) that affect iCloud then you must be prepared for users to get confused when they've switched one on/off and nothing happens. This is also extra code for you to support and, in my opinion, a future potential issue when users think backup is happening but it is not. Leave it to the OS and have the setting where users expect to find it.

Comment: *"Does my app need an iCloud On/Off Switch?"* - absolutely. Some users want nothing to do with a cloud. I still have not accepted  Apple's perverted terms of service for iCloud. My data will never be in their cloud while Apple *and* their partners can be negligent and grossly negligent while handling my data.

Comment: Be aware that the OS settings are Security Settings and should not be confused with a User Preference setting.  The OS does not provide a User Preference setting for your app.  And your App cannot provide a Security Setting, it can only provide a User Preference Setting.  Don't confuse the two.  To further confuse you your App can use a Settings Bundle to provide a means for setting the User Preferences in the OS Settings App or you can provide your own User Settings screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would say it is a bad idea to duplicate functionality built into the OS. In some cases, obviously, there are exceptions, and that would really be up to you. One example I can think of is that if you supported backing up to, say, Dropbox, you might want to have a switch to toggle which backup services to use. If you only optionally support backing up to only iCloud, I would say having the switch in the app would be redundant.

EDIT: I would also mention that I am unaware of any subtle bugs/glitches which might be introduced by taking this philosophy (letting the system do the work) with regard to iCloud backups, but I have not personally heard of any.

Comment: This is a great response, thanks. My intent wasn't to start a philosophical discussion, but to discover unforeseen technical reasons why I might need such a switch (e.g. recovery from database corruption, iCloud sync data loss, etc.).